# Warning in C that says "expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’"

Tags: c

Hello so I have a main fuction where I declare two strings, ask for 2 inputs and call a function that looks like the following, but i have warnings on readString and showF that say "expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’" and i cant understand why:

```
char *originCode;
char *destinationCode;

printf("Insert origin airport code: ");
readString(&originCode, 3);

printf("Insert destination airport code: ");
readString(&destinationCode, 3);
printf("\n");

showF(flights, &originCode, &destinationCode);
```

readString function code:

```
void readString(char *charArr, unsigned int maxChars) {
    fgets(charArr, maxChars, stdin);
    removeNewline(charArr); /* modifies in-place*/
}
```

showF function code:

```
void showF(PtList flights, char *originCode, char *destinationCode) {
    if(flights != NULL && originCode != NULL && destinationCode != NULL) {
        showFlightsWithRoute(flights, originCode, destinationCode);
    }
}
```

showFlightsWithRoute code:

```
void showFlightsWithRoute(PtList flights, char *originCode, char *destinationCode) {
    //create a new list
    PtList list = listCreate();

    //search flights for flights that have the same origin and destination as the ones we want and add them to the new list
    int size;
    listSize(flights, &size);
    Flight flight;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        listGet(flights, i, &flight);
        if(equalsStringIgnoreCase(flight.originAirport, originCode) == 1 && equalsStringIgnoreCase(flight.destinationAirport, destinationCode) == 1)
            listAdd(list, i, flight);
    }

    //print information about the flights
    int newListSize;
    listSize(list, &newListSize);
    Flight elem;
    
    if(newListSize == 0) {
        printf("Flight data not available for route <%s> ==> <%s>", originCode, destinationCode);
    }

    else {
        printf("----------------------------------Flights With Desired Route----------------------------------\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            listGet(list, i, &elem);
            flightPrint(&elem);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking the address of a `char*`, that you do when calling `readString`, yields a `char**`

Comment: Then how do I pass both strings addresses to the readString function?

Comment: Remove the `&` from the function call.

Comment: Hmm did that and got segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: so you recommend declaring originCode and destinationCode both like that? and then what number do I put on the second parameter of readString?

Comment: that sealed the deal thank you very much for your help and sorry for the dumb questions it's my first project using C ^^

Comment: @Mees No worries about the basic question, but I would dispute one aspect of xing's advice.  I recommend not allocating tiny arrays like that for reading a line of text to be typed by the user.  I wouldn't use a size of less than 50 or so.  Memory is cheap, and the problems caused by too-small arrays, if the user types more than you expect, can cost you hours or days of wasted time.

Comment: In your own words: where the code says `char *destinationCode;`, what does that mean? What is the type of `destinationCode`? Therefore, what will be the type of `&destinationCode`? Therefore, where the code says `readString(&destinationCode, 3);`, what type is being used? Do you see how that relates to the error message? Now, look at how `readString` is defined: it says `void readString(char *charArr, unsigned int maxChars) {`. What does that mean? What is the type of `charArr`? Therefore, what type *should* be used? Do you see how *that* relates to the error message?

Comment: "it's my first project using C" Please follow a tutorial all the way through to the end, and make sure you understand all the fundamental concepts, **before** trying to do your own project. Also, if you have not used any other programming languages before, **strongly** consider using **anything other than** C or C++ instead, **especially** if you want to write programs that handle text.

Comment: Its not my first programming project, just the first one with C, and its not my own project, it was assigned by the teachers in my uni. I started with Java during the first semester ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you send char** in functions taking as a parameter a char*.

Here is your main :

```
char *originCode;
char *destinationCode;

printf("Insert origin airport code: ");
readString(&originCode, 3); //needs char*

printf("Insert destination airport code: ");
readString(&destinationCode, 3); //needs char*
printf("\n");

showF(flights, &originCode, &destinationCode); //needs char*
```

The function readString takes a char*, not a char**, so when you call it, you have to call it this way :

```
readString(originCode, 3); //no & before originCode or it sends a char**
...
readString(originCode, 3); //same comment than above
```

It is the same issue with showF : you are sending a char** because you are using & :

```
showF(flights, &originCode, &destinationCode); //wrong
showF(flights, originCode, destinationCode); //right
```

Comment: Then you need to note that the pointers passed to `readString` are uninitialized, so there is undefined behaviour.  And using `fgets()` with a length of 3 will not allow the entry of 3-letter airport codes — it must be at least 4 and even then there are problems because the newline after the airport code will be left to mess up the next input, etc.  A lot of work is needed on the original code.

Comment: Yes, I was just answering the subject question about the compiler warning, even though there are more issues with the code, like at least initializing the pointers to NULL, fgets vs getline with a limit to the upside, etc. many things to be discussed here.